# What is the motivation behind the definition of the matrix sum of a graph?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory

I was studying graph theory using the textbook *Combinatorics and Graph Theory* by Harris, Hirst, and Mossinghoff. In section 1.2, the matrix sum is defined as follows:

> Given a graph $\mathscr{G}$ of order $n$ with adjacency matrix $A$, and given a positive integer $k$, define the matrix sum $S_k$ to be $$S_k = \mathbb{I} + A + A^2 + \ldots + A^k,$$where $\mathbb{I}$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

As I learned, this sum helps us with better methods to find the eccentricity, radius, and diameter of an undirected graph: for example, if $k$ is the smallest positive integer such that row $j$ of $S_k$ contains no zeros, then $\mathrm{ecc}(v_j) = k$. What I don't quite understand yet is why exactly it makes sense to define this sum this way. I understand that this questions is a bit imprecise, but could someone motivate the reason why this definition exists this way?

Comment: How is the above definition different from transitive closure?

Comment: @richard1941 For $k=n$ the nonzero entries do give you the transitive closure. In general this matrix conveys more information: it counts paths too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The adjacency matrix of a graph encodes the edges. Its square encodes paths of length $2$.

The sum in the question is the adjacency matrix for the graph on the the original set of vertices when two vertices are joined by an edge if they are joined in the original graph by a path of of length at most $k$.

The usefulness of this construction encoding paths is the motivation for defining the sum. Algebraically it's a geometric series, which is often convenient.

Comment: Oh this is clear to me now. Thank you professor!

Answer (score 11):

It all comes down to the fact that when $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a graph $\mathcal{G}$, the $(i,j)$-th entry of $A^n$ denotes the number of paths of length exactly $n$ from $v_i$ to $v_j$. For a proof of this fact you can refer [here](https://www.um.edu.mt/library/oar/bitstream/123456789/24439/1/powers%20of%20the%20adjacency%20matrix.pdf).